# iText 5 ColumnText to iText7 ColumnDocumentRenderer alignment issue

Tags: itext7

We are in the process of migrating from iText 5 to iText7. ColumnText is used in few places in our existing code. According to the following https://www.slideshare.net/iTextPDF/oops-i-broke-my-api?from_action=save

we tried to run a sample to test iText7 solution based on ColumnDocumentRenderer. Even though it is working fine, we are seeing a minor difference in the alignment. Apparently, iText5 code is aligning the text to the bottom, but iText7 is not doing that.

iText 5 code

```java
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer =
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("D:\\Temp Files\\Test.pdf"));
document.open();
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
Font normal = new Font(FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12);
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Text", normal);
ct.addElement(p);
int status = ColumnText.START_COLUMN;
Rectangle[] columns = {new Rectangle(36, 36, 290, 806)};
while(ColumnText.hasMoreText(status)) {
    ct.setSimpleColumn(columns[0]);
    status = ct.go();
}
document.close();
```

iText 7 code

```java
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("D:\\Temp Files\\Test i7 ColumnText.pdf"));
Document document = new Document(pdf);
Rectangle[] columns = {new Rectangle(36, 36, 254, 770)};
document.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new StringReader("Text"));
String line;
PdfFont normal = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    document.add(new Paragraph(line).setFont(normal));
}
document.close();
```

There is no alignment or padding set in either case. Not sure if there is anything else that we need to set in iText7. We want to retain the placement of the text, which is very crucial while trying to generate dynamic PDF's. How to maintain the placement of the text between iText 5 and iText 7?

Note: Enclosed screenshot for reference.

[iText5 Vs iText7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbIgD.png)

Left hand side pdf is created by 5 and right hand side is created by 7. The rectangular box was drawn to show how itext 5 is rendering Text aligned to the bottom, but itext 7 is placing the Text little bit above the base line. How to fix itext7 code to place Text similar itext 5?

Comment: Hi, could you explicitly ask your question? Right no I don't see any questions. Also it would be extremely helpful if you attached the screenshots of the current and expected behavior with some explanations. As you have stated the difference is minor so it might not be visible at the first glance to someone who hasn't worked with your code deeply